# Is it possible to shorten conditional statements in cocoa to not re-state the variable name?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Wondering if there is a way to shorthand these conditionals. I am working with data packets and the conditionals get a bit unwieldy at times. Here's a basic example:

I write:

```
if (message->messageType != kMessageTypeCutCardsArray && message->messageType != kMessageTypeQuit) {
    MessageInt message;
    message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeReceivedData;
    NSData *packet = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(message)];
    [_game sendData:packet];
}
```

I would rather write:

```
if (message->messageType != (kMessageTypeCutCardsArray || kMessageTypeQuit)) {
    MessageInt message;
    message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeReceivedData;
    NSData *packet = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(message)];
    [_game sendData:packet];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just commented "incorrect" on your answer, but I think I read too fast. It is correct _if_ `kMessageTypeCutCardsArray` and the other are bit flags -- the single pipe is a binary OR and _will_ combine two (mutally-exclusive) flags so that you can check them at the same time. You should generally use `&` rather than `==` when checking masks like this, however.

Comment: Can you clarify the type of the things you're comparing against?

Comment: You can copy the value into a variable with a shorter name to simplify, i.e., `sometype val = mess->of.an[expression]->goes.here; if((val == this) || (val == that)) {...` (your neighborly compiler will probably do so on its own behind your back anyway)

Comment: Josh, I think you were right and I was incorrect. I am evaluating message types defined in a typedef struct as follows:
typedef enum { ... } MessageType;
typedef struct {
    MessageType messageType;
} Message;

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919800/anyway-to-shorten-if-i-x-i-y

Comment: @echristopherson: Uh, no, if anything the duplication goes the other way because this question is older, but there's no mention in the one you've linked of the data type, which is essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your `enum` such that the values have mutually-exclusive bit patterns, like so:

```
typedef enum : NSUInteger {
    kMessageTypeLoveLetter = 1 << 0,
    kMessageTypeBirthdayCard = 1 << 1,
    kMessageTypeVacationPostcard = 1 << 2,
    kMessageTypeCreditApplication = 1 << 3,
    kMessageTypeCharitySolicitation = 1 << 4
} MessageType;
```

You can then test for multiple values at once, using binary OR `|` and binary AND `&`:

```
MessageType msgType = kMessageTypeCreditApplication;

if( !(msgType & (kMessageTypeLoveLetter | kMessageTypeBirthdayCard)) ){
    // Nobody loves you.
}
if( (msgType & (kMessageTypeCreditApplication | kMessageTypeCharitySolicitation) ){
    // Someone wants your money.
}
```

This won't work, however, if you use the compiler-generated consecutive values for the `enum`, because the values will overlap as flags -- e.g., both 2 and 3 have the lowest bit set -- and ORing them together will often end up testing only one of the flags.

Comment: I didn't make this technique up; it's about as old as C!

Comment: I've seen bitwise operations in use before, I haven't defined bit patterns in typedefs however. Although, definitely could be my relatively small experience with straight C. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Glad it's helpful! Off the top of my head, one place in Cocoa that you'll see bit masks is for keyboard handling -- the modifier keys are indicated with masks in `NSEvent`s and when setting key equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

As a general matter, no.  That's just the way that C (and hence Objective-C) works.

In this specific case, you could use a `switch` statement:

```
switch (message->messageType)
{
    case kMessageTypeCutCardsArray:
    case kMessageTypeQuit:
        break;
    default:
        MessageInt message;
        message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeReceivedData;
        NSData *packet = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(message)];
        [_game sendData:packet];
        break;
}
```

Whether that syntax is an improvement is up to you.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks for the switch idea, but in this case I want to do something if it's anything except for one of those 2 message types.

Comment: Oops! I misread that. You can still use a switch to express that logic and I've updated my answer to show how. (Makes the syntax even less compact and more cumbersome, though.)

Answer (score 0):

You could box the values and use a temporary array. This achieves the goal of removing the duplication in the conditional, but is unlikely to be as optimizable for the compiler.

```
if (message->messageType != kMessageTypeCutCardsArray && 
    message->messageType != kMessageTypeQuit) {
```

should be equivalent to:

```
if(![@[@(kMessageTypeCutCardsArray),@(kMessageTypeQuit)] 
     contains:@(message->messageType)]) {
```